# Populating an asp.net treeview with a complex dataset

Tags: c#, asp.net, treeview, dataset

I have application that is returning a dataset in the format below:

> ```
> Path              Parent Path     EntityID    EntityName                      sysID
> /5344/5558/5554/  /5344/5558/     3           New York (City of)              5554
> /5344/5558/5556/  /5344/5558/     3           Albany (City of)                5556
> /5344/5558/5553/  /5344/5558/     3           White Plains (City of)          5553
> /5344/5558/5557/  /5344/5558/     3           Buffalo (City of)               5557
> /5344/5558/       /5344/          2           State Of New York               5558
> /5344/5558/5555/  /5344/5558/     3           Syracuse (City Of)              5555
> /5344/5920/5921/  /5344/5920/     3           West Palm Beach (City Of)       5921
> /5344/5920/6853/  /5344/5920/     3           Ft. Lauderdale (City Of)        6853
> /5344/5920/6043/  /5344/5920/     3           Orlando (City Of)               6043
> /5344/5920/       /5344/          2           State Of Florida                5920
> /5344/5529/5527/  /5344/5529/     3           Sacramento (City Of)            5527
> /5344/5529/       /5344/          2           State Of California             5529
> /5344/            /               1           USA                             5344
> ```

I need to populate a TreeView control with the EntityName (must be alphabetically sorted) and the sysID values.

EntityID is the node level of the record (1 is the root, 2 is parent, 3 is child).
The Path & ParentPath are a result of manupilating another field (not shown here) which has a data type of hierarchyid.

This is slightly more complex than your generic "populate a treeview" posts that I found in my searches.

I have been trying to populate the treeview control, but unable to figure out how to do it.
Any suggestions on how to populate a treeview given the dataset?

Comment: Working on the same think right now, can you please share the solution? thanks.